# How to copy the data from one cell if the condition is met and place it into another cell

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, worksheet

I just want to make making attendance in a meeting easier. I have a list of names on the other side, and I will put "p" if they are present. How can I make it trigger to copy the name of the person to other cell if I put "P"on the cell beside it

Comment: What kind of cell is it? Spreadsheet? DataGrid? What have you tried?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HYZ0.png) is what you want your excel to do, then you can write an if statement in the "Present" column  like so `IF(B1 = "p", B1, "")`.

Comment: Thankkkkkk youuuu so much! <3